# How to pull data from particular date and rest all normal?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a sql query which working fine. But business wants "from 8/2019 to present data regardless if it is FULFILL_STATUS_CODE active or expired".

Current only pulling Active data when passing `@OrderDate > '01/01/2014' but now we need to get` Active`or`Expired`orders from  01/08/2019 and`@OrderDate >'01/01/2014'`

This means Orders from `01/01/2014 to 07/31/2019` only `Active` and 01/08/2019 above `Active` or `Expired`

How to change below SQL query?

```
 Select ORDER_NO,SHIP_LABEL_NAME AS CUSTOMER_NAME, ORDER_DATE, PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, PARENT_PRODUCT, 
INVOICE_NO, INVOICE_DATE, DUE_DATE, LINE_STATUS_CODE, LINE_STATUS_DATE, SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID, 
FULFILL_STATUS_CODE, RATE_STRUCTURE, RATE_CODE, ACTUAL_UNIT_PRICE, BASE_TOTAL_AMOUNT, ACTUAL_TOTAL_AMOUNT,
PRODUCT_LONG_NAME AS DESCRIPTION, INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE, CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE, CYCLE_END_DATE from 
ORDER_DETAIL_CUS_INFO_VW Where 
FULFILL_STATUS_CODE ='A' AND
(RATE_STRUCTURE = 'ACADEMIC' OR 
RATE_STRUCTURE = 'BUSCORP') AND 
PARENT_PRODUCT = 'ONE' AND 
LINE_STATUS_CODE ='A' AND ORDER_DATE>=@OrderDate ORDER BY ORDER_NO
```

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images). Simplify! [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
FULFILL_STATUS_CODE ='A'
```

to this:

```
FULFILL_STATUS_CODE IN ('A','whatever means expired')
```

Comment: My @OrderDate still '01/01/2014' but Orders from 01/01/2014 to 07/31/2019 only Active and 01/08/2019 above Active or Expired